# Can I use clustering as a filter of data?

Tags: clustering, python

I want to filter a dataset depending on the patterns of data. I think about clustering to do it. In the image of the middle there are some data points I want to filter(because they have a horizontal tendency and they are not at the top of the curve). Is it possible to do it with clustering? Or I misunderstood the concept of it?

It is a question about the concept, I haven't tried any code yet.

[image: curtailment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems more of an **outlier/novelty detection** task. Roughly speaking the goal in these settings is to examine what parts of the data "don't fit" based on their attribute realizations.
I personally like the brief overview that the s[klearn documentation provides on the topic](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html), but implementations of various methods should be available in all common programming languages.

Nonetheless, I could image that [DBSCAN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#dbscan) would do a decent job at clustering the data in your example and either denoting the encircled points as different cluster or outliers.

Comment: thanks! I will take a look to the links and I will try to implement something.

Comment: @deemelCan you classify this a as a problem to be solved using a Support Vector Machine?

Comment: Without knowing the data set, I can only guess. I would assume it should be working fine, however I would start with something less sensitive to the choice of it's hyperparameters. Off the top of my head I'd think of an isolation forest or even a bayesian GMM, but again you need to see what works well for your data

Comment: thanks for the explanation @deemel!